# PHPmailer and serve limit

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm having some problem with a script that send bulk email through PHPmailer class because i exced email per hour limit of my hosting.

I didn't find any option to schedule email, could it be possible to set a delay or time when the email should be send?

Which is the best way, or work around, to send email on scheduled time?

Comment: You could perhaps use a cron job if your hosting company permits it.

Comment: without modifying the all script is not possible

Comment: You can count the emails you have send, when you have reach the limit e-mail you will exit the script. You can run a cronjon every hour to send the emails. Everytime you have send a e-mail you can delete the record in the database or your can update a field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Download a solution specially for newsletters and stuff , in PHP , the most common one is called PHPList , this solution have alot of options that will do schedule and the timeout time automatically for you .